# How to keep textfield style when submit button is clicked?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I've got a search bar with a submit button in a form. I made it so that when the mouse is hovered over the form, the button will appear, and when the text field is in focus, the bar will stay shown and the field will darken in color. Now, when I click the submit button, the text field loses focus.

Is there a way to keep the style of the text field when the submit button is clicked? As in, when the text field is focused and you click the submit button, it stays focused (or the style doesn't change), and if the textfield is not in focus and you click the submit button, it doesn't focus (or the style doesn't change). I'm looking for a non-javascript solution.

[image: States]

Here's the HTML:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform d-1of3 t-3of8 m-all" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
      <input type="search" class="search-field m-text-center" placeholder="'.__( 'Search for...', 'bones' ).'" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" title="Search" />
      <input type="submit" class="search-icon fa" value="&#xf002;" />
</form>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
form#searchform
{
    position: relative;

    padding-right: 43px;
}
form#searchform input[type='search'].search-field
{
    padding-right: 36px;

    text-indent: 36px;
}
form#searchform input[type='submit']
{
    font: normal normal normal 2em/1 FontAwesome;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    width: 36px;
    padding: 3px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;

    color: #95070a;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
}
form#searchform input[type='submit'].search-icon.fa:active
{
    zoom: 1;

    opacity: 1;

    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
form#searchform input[type='search'].search-field:focus + input.search-icon,
form#searchform input[type='submit'].search-icon:hover
{
    zoom: 1;

    opacity: .75;

    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
form#searchform:hover input.search-icon,
.search-icon
{
    zoom: 1;

    opacity: .5;

    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.no-touch .search-icon
{
    opacity: 0;

    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want solution with only css?

Comment: @wishall Yes, please!